# How to set modelformset widget.label with value of other model field?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I have a modelformset for a `PersonTag` model with 3 fields, and I want to display a checkbox widget for the `PersonTag.enabled` field, and no widget for the other two fields.  For each checkbox, I want the label to be set to the `PersonTag.tag` value for that model instance.  How might I accomplish this?

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name_person = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', through='PersonTag')

class Tag(models.Model):
    name_tag = models.TextField()
    persons_tagged = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through='PersonTag')

class PersonTag(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Tag')
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.forms.widgets import HiddenInput
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render

from models import Person, PersonTag, Tag

def home(request):
    # Should I use a HiddenInput here for 'tag', or is it not necessary?
    ModelFormset_PersonTag = modelformset_factory(model=PersonTag,
                                                  extra=0,
                                                  fields=('enabled','tag',),
                                                  widgets=dict(tag=HiddenInput()))
    # Arbitrarily choose a person for this example
    person = Person.objects.all()[0]
    if request.method == 'GET':
        modelformset_persontag = ModelFormset_PersonTag(
                            queryset=PersonTag.objects.filter(person=person))
        for form in modelformset_persontag.forms:
            # How to reference the .tag.label value here?
            form.fields['enabled'].label = form.fields['tag'].widget.???
        return render(request=request,
                      template_name='home.html',
                      dictionary=dict(
                                modelformset_persontag=modelformset_persontag))
```

**home.html:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="">  {% csrf_token %}
        {{ modelformset_persontag.management_form }}

        {% for form_persontag in modelformset_persontag %}
            {{ form_persontag }}
        {% endfor %}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that I like:

```
form.fields['enabled'].label = form.instance.tag.name_tag
```

The `PersonTag.tag` field with a `HiddenValue` widget is not needed (though it could be used if desired):

```
ModelFormset_PersonTag = modelformset_factory(model=PersonTag,
                                              extra=0,
                                              fields=('enabled',))
```

Though no longer needed, I am curious how the value from `form.fields['tag'].widget.???` could be obtained.